# Markdown - imported file not writing escaped characters in fences

Tags: markdown, assemble

Imported `md` files seem to not be rendering escaped characters in fences (keeping in mind that `assemble` notes `md` as a renderer out of the box). Below is a test I ran with `assemble` [built into a node API](https://github.com/DigitalKrony/FrameworkAlpha/blob/master/local_modules/FrameworkAlphaAssemble/index.js) renderer. While building out the base system I noticed that `markdown` fences aren't working when in an imported `md` file but do work when written directly in the `hbs` file. I've looked all over the `assemble` documentation, as well as the 'markdown' and 'helpers-markdown' docs but, have had no luck.

Am I missing a step in the pipeline or is this a bug that needs to be filed against `assemble`/`markdown`?

### test.hbs

````
---
docSrc: src/ to/ doc.md
---
{{md docSrc}}

{{#markdown}}
    ``` html
    <a href="">anchor</a>
    ```
{{/markdown}}
````

### doc.md

````
# Anchor

### best practices

    ``` html
    <a href="#">anchor</a>
    ```
````

### RENDERED HTML

```
<pre>
    <code class="lang-html">
        <a href="#">anchor</a>
    </code>
</pre>


<pre>
    <code class="language-html">
        &lt;a href=""&gt;anchor&lt;/a&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{{md}}` helper is coming from [helper-md](https://github.com/helpers/helper-md) and its decoding html elements after rendering the markdown. If you open an issue there (or submit a PR) we can discuss it there.